# ESQL - Does anyone know of a tool which can provide static code analysis for ESQL?

Tags: sql, code-analysis, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am writing a large application and was wanting to conduct static code analysis on my code, however I am struggling to find a tool which can do this for ESQL.

I have used SonarQube before with Java, but there is no ESQL or SQL plugin, just PL/SQL which you have to pay for.

Or even a plug in for SonarQube if anyone knows one?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like exists a plugin for sonar now: https://github.com/EXXETA/sonar-esql-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I'm aware of is this supportpac:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&q1=xa03&uid=swg24012060&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

It only does a very narrow analysis looking for one particular problem and is somewhat outdated so I'm not sure how much use this will be.

I'd suggest that asking for static analysis tools would make a great "Request For Enhancement" (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532)

Of course the toolkit itself does provide some analysis during building of the project but I gather you're looking for something more substantial.